# Excel: Visual Basic: range as function input doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm starting with VB in Excel; so far I can't figure the following;
I've got the following function:

```
Function testGetRange(myRange As Range)
    Dim weekStart As Integer
    Dim weekEnd As Integer

    weekStart = myRange(1).Value
    weekEnd = myRange(2).Value
End Function
```

If I try to execute it like that:

```
Sub CreationRapport()
    Dim testRange1 As Range
    Set testRange1 = Range("A5:B5")

    testGetRange (testRange1)
End Sub
```

I've got an error like "object needed" (sorry the error message is in French: "objet requis"), stopping right when I try to execute the function.

So: the range is created, the function takes a range as input; don't know why this doesn't work...

Comment: A function typically returns something at the the end, like: `testGetRange = ...`. I use "..." because I can't tell what you want it to return or do. Perhaps you just need a Sub that performs an action. It would be helpful to know what you want to happen.

Comment: testGetRange(myRange As Range) As String [...] testGetRange = weekStart doesn't change a thing :/

Comment: Please read some basic materials on VBA Functions and Subs. Also, as I suggested, telling us what you hope to have happen would really help. Otherwise we have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a function and the parantheses signify that you want the function to return something:

```
testGetRange (testRange1)
```

But your function doesn't return anything. You can fix this by adding this to testGetRange:

```
testGetRange ="My return output"
```

...And you don't put the output anywhere. You can fix this by changing in CreationRapport:

```
MyOutput = testGetRange (testRange1)
msgbox MyOutput
```

Comment: Your last part was the answer: `MyOutput = testGetRange (testRange1)`, after initializing MyOutput, made it work. Plus, I got an error when setting `weekStart` and `weekEnd`. Will post my solution just below :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function but don't want a return value you need to either leave off the parenthesis

```
Sub CreationRapport()
    Dim testRange1 As Range
    Set testRange1 = Range("A5:B5")

    testGetRange testRange1
End Sub
```

Or use call

```
Sub CreationRapport()
    Dim testRange1 As Range
    Set testRange1 = Range("A5:B5")

    Call testGetRange (testRange1)
End Sub
```

For the why you can see how VBA handles transferring control to a sub or function [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcx04ck5(VS.85%29.aspx)

> You are not required to use the Call keyword when calling a procedure.
>   However, if you use the Call keyword to call a procedure that requires
>   arguments, argumentlist must be enclosed in parentheses. If you use
>   either Call syntax to call any intrinsic or user-defined function, the
>   function's return value is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after testing the different answers, this worked:

```
Function testGetRange(myRange As Range) As String
    Dim weekStart As String
    Dim weekEnd As String

    weekStart = myRange(1)
    weekEnd = myRange(2)

    testGetRange = weekStart
End Function
```

And in the Sub:

```
Sub CreationRapport()
    Dim myOutput As String
    Dim testRange1 As Range
    Set testRange1 = Range("A5:B5")

    myOutput = testGetRange(testRange1)
    MsgBox myOutput
End Sub
```

The MsgBox is not mandatory, but the part `myOutput = testGetRange(testRange1)` is!
So, as advised by Doug, need to work more on the VB to see why it is. Thank you all :)